# How to use Quartz.net with F#

Tags: f#, quartz.net

I cannot make F# to schedule simple scheduler based on [this](http://www.fssnip.net/ec/title/Quartz-Job-Scheduling) .

```
open System
open Quartz
open Quartz.Impl

let schedulerFactory = StdSchedulerFactory()
let scheduler  = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler()
scheduler.Start()

type Job () =

    interface IJob with

        member x.Execute(context: IJobExecutionContext) =
            task{       //
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now)
            }

let job = JobBuilder.Create<Job>().Build() //Exception Unhandled error!

let trigger =
    TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithSimpleSchedule(fun x ->
            x.WithIntervalInSeconds(1).RepeatForever() |> ignore)
        .Build()

scheduler.Result.ScheduleJob(job, trigger) |> ignore
Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000000)
Console.ReadKey()|>ignore
```

It gives runtime error for line `let job = JobBuilder.Create<Job>().Build()` System.InvalidOperationException: 'Start may not be called on a task that has completed.'

I also have had to change the scheduler.ScheduleJob to the scheduler.Result.ScheduleJob(.. from the original example above.

Comment: I'm not sure, but check this: https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/migration-guide.html#api-changes

Comment: i did, but all examples are in c# and it is hard to convert especially async await code to f#

Comment: FYI the exception is not thrown on the line you mention, it is thrown on line 7, `scheduler.Start()`

Comment: I tried it in LINQPad 7, and the same exception threw in both places at different runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the documentation that Bent pointed to, I think this should do it, using the `task` builder from F# 6:

```ml
open System
open System.Threading.Tasks

open Quartz
open Quartz.Impl

type Job() =
    interface IJob with
        member _.Execute(_context) =
            Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(DateTime.Now.ToString())

task {
    // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory
    let factory = StdSchedulerFactory()
    let! scheduler = factory.GetScheduler()

    // and start it off
    do! scheduler.Start()

    // define the job and tie it to our Job class
    let job =
        JobBuilder.Create<Job>()
            .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
            .Build()

    // Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every second
    let trigger =
        TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(fun x ->
                x.WithIntervalInSeconds(1).RepeatForever()
                    |> ignore)
            .Build()

    // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
    let! _offset = scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger)

    // some sleep to show what's happening
    do! Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))

    // and last shut down the scheduler when you are ready to close your program
    do! scheduler.Shutdown()
} |> ignore

Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

Output is something like:

```
4/16/2022 6:11:52 PM
4/16/2022 6:11:52 PM
4/16/2022 6:11:53 PM
4/16/2022 6:11:54 PM
4/16/2022 6:11:55 PM
4/16/2022 6:11:56 PM
4/16/2022 6:11:57 PM
4/16/2022 6:11:58 PM
4/16/2022 6:11:59 PM
4/16/2022 6:12:00 PM
4/16/2022 6:12:01 PM
```